# Manage KeyError with gensim and pretrained word2vec model

Tags: python, nlp, gensim

I pretrained a word embedding using wang2vec (https://github.com/wlin12/wang2vec), and i loaded it in python through gensim. When i tried to get the vector of some words not in vocabulary, i obviously get:

```py
KeyError: "word 'kjklk' not in vocabulary"
```

So, i thought about adding an item to the vocabulary to map oov (out of vocabulary) words, let's say `<OOV>`. Since the vocabulary is in `Dict` format, i would simply add the item `{"<OOV>":0}`.

But, i searched an item of the vocabulary, with

```py
model = gensim.models.KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(w2v_ext, binary=False, unicode_errors='ignore')
dict(list(model.vocab.items())[5:6])
```

The output was something like

```py
{'word': <gensim.models.keyedvectors.Vocab at 0x7fc5aa6007b8>}
```

So, is there a way to add the `<OOV>` token to the vocabulary of a pretrained word embedding loaded through gensim, and avoid the KeyError? I looked at gensim doc and i found this: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/word2vec.html#gensim.models.word2vec.Word2Vec.build_vocab
but it seems not work with the update parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a synthetic `'<OOV>'` token would just let you look up that token, like `model['<OOV>']`.The model would still give key errors for absent keys like `'kjklk'`.

There's no built-in support for adding any such 'catch-all' mapping. Often, ignoring unknown tokens is better than using some plug value (such as a zero-vector or random-vector).

It's fairly idiomatic in Python to explicitly check if a key is present, via the `in` keyword, if you want to do something different for absent keys. For example:

```
vector = model['kjklk'] if 'kjklk' in model else DEFAULT_VECTOR
```

(Notably, the `*expr1* if *expr2* else *expr3*` defers evaluation of the initial *expr1*, avoiding `KeyError`.)

Python also has the `defaultdict` variant dictionary, which can have a default value returned for any unknown key. See:

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict

It'd be possible to try replacing the `KeyedVectors` `vocab` dictionary with one of those, if the behavior is really important, but there could be side effects on other code.